# how to clear the wireshark filter combo contents

Tags: wireshark

Does anyone know how to clear the filter drop down (combo) contents in Wireshark?  Are the contents stored in a file somewhere?

For the life of me, I can't figure this out.  And, the Wireshark help file only tells me "The entries in the pull down list will remain available even after a program restart."

Answer (score 2):

Sigh...

Answered my own question.

The filter history is stored in 
c:\documents and settings\foo\Application Data\Wireshark\recent, where "foo" is your windows user name.

I don't use Wireshark in Linux, so I don't know where this file lives there.  I would imagine in your home directory.

In that file, there's a section labeled "######## Recent display filters (latest last), cannot be altered through command line ########".  Each recent.display_filter line is an entry in the filter drop down.  Just remove the filters you don't want in the drop down, or remove them all to clear the filter history entirely.

Answer (score 1):

They're in `~/.wireshark/recent` and named "recent.display_filter".

Comment: Thanks!  I found this not long after I posted the question.

Answer (score 0):

This is now in  %APPDATA%\Wireshark\recent_common

AKA C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Wireshark\recent_common

Look for the   ######## Recent display filters (latest last), cannot be altered through command line ######## section.

Answer (score 0):

I found how we can remove saved wireshark filters on Windows10 systems:
First you have to go to this directory C:\Users\<your_username>\AppData\Roaming\Wireshark and open the recent_common file with any text editor and then press on CTRL + f search the name of the filter that you want to delete and delete the whole line and the filter will never come back!

I hope I could help you.